# RNN classifier for generating advices

Tags: python, tokenize

I am try to make a project in which farming advice are generated based on weather condition on a specific district. I have a sample dataset for now, as shown below.

| state | district | month | rainfall | max_temp | min_temp | max_rh | min_rh | wind_speed | advice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orissa | Kendrapada | february | 0.0 | 34.6 | 19.4 | 88.2 | 29.6 | 12.0 | chances of foot rot disease in paddy crop; apply urea at 3 weeks after transplanting at active tillering stage for paddy;...... |
| Jharkhand | Saraikela Kharsawan | february | 0 | 35.2 | 16.6 | 29.4 | 11.2 | 3.6 | provide straw mulch and go for intercultural operations to avoid moisture losses from soil; chance of leaf blight disease in potato crop; ....... |

I want to use this dataset to generate advice for farmers based on weather conditions. I have already tokenized the advice column and here is the preview. [Tokenized advice image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91wYL.png)

Code using which it was tokenized:

```
tokenizer= Tokenizer()
token_advice=[]
for i in df['advice']:
   tokenizer.fit_on_texts(i)
   sq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(i)
   pda=pad_sequences(sq,padding='pre', truncating='post', maxlen=30)
   token_advice.append(pda)
df['token_advice']=token_advice
```

Now, I want to train a model using the dataset and be able to generate advices. I am new to Machine Learning. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (tl;dr: **never**).

Answer (score 0):

How big is your dataset? and How many categories do you have?

If is not big, and you have only two categories use a tree model.

Comment: My dataset will be having around 37336 records with only the columns that is shown here. The State column will have only 29 different types data and district will have around 715 types data. Rest the data will be for every week of two consecutive years.